# How to add node in binary tree

Tags: tree, binary-tree

> ```
>                    (5)Root
>           (3)-------^--------(7)
>      (2)---^----(5)           ^-----(8)
> ```

I want to add node with data 5 in this binary Search tree. Please help.

Comment: you need to provide a bit more info.. e.g. programming language and what you have so far.

Comment: how did you add the other `5`s?

Comment: actually, if it's a binary search tree, then it's wrong.

Comment: i need algorithm, but i will implement it in java later...i have code but it is not working.....it adds nodes but when i add 5 as root and again when i add 5 in it did not display it after traversing..

Now i have to add node in above tree i know it will be added left of node 5 but i can't do it...

Comment: assuming it's a binary search tree, check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Note:* This answer assumes you are talking about a binary search tree.

You traverse the binary tree from the root:

- if your new element is less or equal than the current node, you go to the left subtree, otherwise to the right subtree and continue traversing
- if you arrived at a node, where you can not go any deeper, because there is no subtree, this is the place to insert your new element

  ```
                 (5)Root
        (3)-------^--------(7)
   (2)---^----(5)           ^-----(8)
          (5)--^
  ```

You start at `(5)`, then go left (since 5 <= 5) to `(3)`, then go right (since 5 > 3) to `(5)`, then you want to go to the left subtree (since 5 <= 5), but you see that there is no subtree, so this is the place to insert your new element `(5)`.

Comment: So the OP did say it was a Binary Tree, you have provided an answer that is more or less for a Binary Search Tree though you would not allow a duplicate 5 to be added to a Binary Search Tree

Comment: This is wrong: you can't have duplicate values in a binary search tree.

Comment: @Saurabh I guess it depends on your definition, and for certain situations it is convenient to disallow duplicate values, while others are fine with them. The question seems seek for explanations on the basic concepts of a binary tree, so I thought that covering (one way of) how to deal with duplicate elements makes sense here.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether you want to keep your binary tree:

- sorted
- balanced

If neither of these are requirements then the fastest way to add an element is to put it as the new root and have the rest of the tree has one of its children:

```
                         (5)
                   (5)----^
          (3)-------^--------(7)
     (2)---^----(5)           ^-----(8)
```

For binary search trees you should not have repeated values and the process for insertion is more complicated and requires traversing the tree to find the insertion point. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree).

For self-balancing binary search trees it is even more complicated and can for example involve performing [tree rotations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_rotation). See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Insert(Node node, ref Node tree)
{    
        if (tree == null)                          // Found a leaf?    
        {                                      
             tree = node;                          // Found it! Add the new node as the new leaf.
        }    
        else    
        {        
             int val = string.Compare(node.Key, tree.Key);        // already inserted        
             if (val == 0)
             {            
                  throw new InvalidOperationException("Duplicate key");
             }        
             elseif (val < 0)        
             {            
                  Node left = tree.Left;            
                  Insert(node, ref left);              // Keep moving down the left side.            
                  tree.Left = left;        
             }        
             else        
             {            
                  Node right = tree.Right;         
                  Insert(node, ref right);            // Keep moving down the right side.            
                  tree.Right = right;        
             }    
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/// <summary>
    /// Construct the tree from a pre order traversal
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="preorderTraversal"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static TreeNode ConstructTreeFromPreOrderTraversal(int[] preorderTraversal)
    {

        if (null == preorderTraversal || preorderTraversal.Length < 1)
            return null;
        TreeNode root = null;
        int len = preorderTraversal.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode();
            newNode.Data = preorderTraversal[i];
            newNode.Left = newNode.Right = null;
            AddNode(ref root, newNode);
        }
        return root;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// add not in the tree
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="root"></param>
    /// <param name="newNode"></param>
    private static void AddNode(ref TreeNode root, TreeNode newNode)
    {
        if (root == null)
            root = newNode;
        else if (newNode.Data < root.Data)
        {
            TreeNode left = root.Left;
            AddNode(ref left, newNode);
            root.Left = left;
        }
        else
        {
            TreeNode right = root.Right;
            AddNode(ref right, newNode);
            root.Right = right;
        }
    }
```